# Book cover photo of actor and their "Right of publicity"

Tags: right-of-publicity

I see unauthorized, unflattering books in the US about celebrities all the time that use that celebrity's image on the book (clearly NOT with their express permission) - because the book is non-fiction/editorial there is no redress for that celebrity wrt their right of publicity in a particular US state (for example, California)? (this is not a photo copyright question)

I'm finishing up a self-published book about the making of an old movie. I've long since decided to give the book a plain cover to avoid issues regarding US actors right of publicity, but like many things in this area it seems a bit grey and I'm curious.

See [Are Name, Image and Likeness (NIL) of public athletes protected by copyright?](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/83153/are-name-image-and-likeness-nil-of-public-athletes-protected-by-copyright)

Comment: Right of publicity is only existent in some countries

Comment: Good point. I'll clarify my question.

Comment: and only some US states recognize a right of publicity. Of those that do, the terms vary.

Comment: That's true; as far as I'm aware there are no federal statutes pertaining to rights of publicity.

Answer (score 2):

Some but not all US states, and some but not all countries, recognize a "right of publicity".

[ohio](/questions/tagged/ohio)

In Ohio, the "Right of publicity" is protected by [Chapter 2741](https://codes.ohio.gov/ohio-revised-code/chapter-2741) of the Ohio Revised Code. This right extends to various aspects of a person's "persona", and may be enforced by a civil suit.

In Ohio such a cover image would be a violation of the right of publicity **unless** the work on which it appears, or whch it is used to promote is a "historical work", a "literary work" or a "work of fiction". Those uses are exempt from these rights.

Comment: For clarification, did you cite Ohio as a random example, or does it represent one extreme? To find out if one can legally put Bill Gates' picture on the cover of a book about Bill Gates that is published not in Ohio but in California, Washington, etc. one would just have to research the law in those particular states, right?